# Can the statements char str[]="abcdef"; and char *str="abcdef"; be used to explain the char array and string literal in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Can the statements

```
char str[]="abcdef";
```

and

```
char *str="abcdef";
```

be used to explain the char array and string literal in C?
What is relationship between char array and string literal?
What is actually usage of char array except storing a string literal?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/strlitnomod.html http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html

Comment: Another question: in statement char str[]="abcdef"; Is the str a char array, is "abcdef" a string literal?

Comment: That's correct, `str` is a `char` array, and `"abcdef"` is a string literal - which is a special kind of `char` array.

Comment: @DanielFischer string literal is a special kind of char array, what is its special point?

Comment: They're unmodifiable (trying to modify one is UB). The compiler-inserted 0-terminator can also be considered special. But mostly, it's that they're unmodifiable although their type is plan `char[strlen(string) + 1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string literal is an array of `char` that is not modifiable.

C99 6.4.5 p2:

> A *character string literal* is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in "xyz".

And then, in C99 6.4.5 p5:

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
>   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. The multibyte character
>   sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have
>   type **`char`**, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
>   sequence;...

The draft C11 I have has similar wording. I believe it is worded with "have type `char`" precisely to allow a string literal to be assigned to `char *`. However, the standard does go on to say in C99 6.4.5 p6:

> If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

So assignable, but not modifiable.

A string literal can be used as an initializer for an array of `char`. From C99 6.7.8 p14:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally
>   enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your second assignment is erronous. It should be a `const char *` - string literals, when assigned to a pointer, are constants, but they become modifiable when they initialize an *array*. For example, you couldn't use the 2nd version in a call to `strtok()` (google its man page to see why!)

Comment: So what if I later want to point `str` at modifiable data ?

Comment: you have to either `strdup()` it OR `strcpy()` to a non-const buffer.

Comment: **Or** I could just not make it `const` in the first place and just change the pointer.

Comment: @cnicutar no. The string literal itself is created read-only by the compiler and it'll segfault (so please revoke your downvote).

Comment: H2CO3 I didn't downvote (you can look at my vote count). I think you also misread my comments. I know full well literals are non-modifiable. I was just asking, what if you want to make `str` point to an object that **is modifiable** ? I.e. I was challenging your first statement that the `const` is needed.

Comment: @Flexo Why won't anyone read carefully :-) You can't point a `const` pointer at non-`const` data.

Comment: You *can* point a `const` pointer at non-`const` data. And you should prefer that to doing the opposite. If you use the same pointer variable both for pointing at unmodifiable strings and modifiable strings, it should be a pointer-to-const. If you need to actually use that variable to do the modifying of a modifiable string, change your design.

Comment: @AlanCurry You can point it but it won't do you much good if you need to change the object. That's why one shouldn't throw `const` everywhere "because it's safer".

Comment: Think of `const char *` as meaning "pointer to char" and `char *` as meaning "pointer to char **and I intend to modify it**"

Comment: @cnicutar if you're using a `const char *`, you can modify the **pointer** itself, you just can't do like `pointer[1] = 'a';` -- a const char * is **not** a const pointer to a char, but a non-const pointer to a const char.

Comment: I said it three times already. Let's say I have a `char modifiable[100]`. And I want to point your `const char *str` at it. I can, of course. **But I can't use it to modify it** -  the const stops me from doing so.

Comment: @cnicutar of course it does. But why would you want to reuse a pointer to a string literal to point to a non-literal string?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just challenging your first statement that the pointer automatically should be a `const char *`. Maybe it should, maybe it shouldn't.

Comment: @cnicutar it should, because you can assign a const char * to a char *, but not vice versa.

Comment: @H2CO3 “you can assign a const char * to a char *, but not vice versa” Are you saying that one cannot assign a char * expression to a const char * lvalue? Considering that this is exactly what you are suggesting to do —string literals have type char[] in C, no const— I have a hard time understanding what you are getting at.

Comment: @PascalCuoq sorry, I meant exactly the opposite. I'll add the correct comment.

Comment: @cnicutar so it should be a const char, because you can assign a char * to a pointer of type const char *, but you can't assign a const char * value to a char * variable.